# addView causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, achartengine

Good day!
I'm implementing aChartEngine to draw charts on Android and have faced with a trouble: I  receive NullPointerException when try to add created chart view to layout with addView method.

**chart_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/charts_relative_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:name="@+id/price_chart"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
// other elements
</RelativeLayout>
```

Charts.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chart_layout);
     //other code
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (chart_price == null) { 
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.price_chart);
    chart_price = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, buildDataset(getTitles(), dateArray, priceArray), getRenderrer(paramList.get(0).length, paramList.get(1).length, maxPrice));          
    layout.addView(chart_price);    // THIS LINE CAUSES NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    }
    else {
      chart_price.repaint();
    }
 }
```

Are any ideas, what can be the reason of this error?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's the layout that is cause the NPE or whether it's the chart_price?

Comment: I used the code below and it displayed that chart_price is NOT null. My guess, error cause either addView method or settings of chart_layout.xml. ::::::::::::::::: System.out.println("Before ADDVIEW");
      System.out.println(chart_price == null);
      layout.addView(chart_price);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your xml file.

```
    android:name="@+id/price_chart"
```

should be

```
    android:id="@+id/price_chart"
```

Comment: Thank a lot that you pointed on my mistake! Now it works properly!

Answer (score 0):

Make any change to your XML file and then save and run it again. Worked for me when I had a problem earlier tonight that was similar.

Comment: I have changed this file many times, but it hasn't any positive effect. Even tried to change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout ... it didn't help too. What changes exactly helped you?

Comment: Noel has posted the answer to your problem, so ignore mine as it wasn't your issue.