# AchartEngine - AddView on layout causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, achartengine

i am trying to get rid of that error but i don't see anything wrong (for me) ; 
someone get that problem too but its was a bad id given to the layout : [addView causes NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318903/addview-causes-nullpointerexception)

I took a simple code sample from http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/achartengine-charting-library-for.html

```
public class LineGraph extends Activity {

    private GraphicalView mChart;
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
    private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

    private void initChart() {
        mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Sample Data");
        mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
        mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
    }

    private void addSampleData() {
        mCurrentSeries.add(1, 2);
        mCurrentSeries.add(2, 3);
        mCurrentSeries.add(3, 2);
        mCurrentSeries.add(4, 5);
        mCurrentSeries.add(5, 4);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graph);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChart == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            initChart();
            addSampleData();
            mChart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, 0.3f);

         // Here is the problem => layout.addView(mChart);

        } else {
            mChart.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

and my XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

May be i missed an obvious mistake but the addView() gives me a nullPointerException, please someone can tell me what i have done wrong?

EDIT : And the stacktrace

```
05-17 14:37:05.830: E/SensorManager(6703): thread start
05-17 14:37:06.885: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6703): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-17 14:37:06.885: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6703): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.smartdroid/com.smartdroid.LineGraph}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at com.smartdroid.LineGraph.onResume(LineGraph.java:64)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1188)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
05-17 14:37:28.800: E/AndroidRuntime(6703):     ... 12 more
05-17 14:38:45.465: E/SensorManager(8335): thread start
05-17 14:38:46.630: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8335): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-17 14:38:46.630: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8335): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: I'm afraid to seem stupid but you mean all messages from logcat when i start my application, right?

Comment: no only error stacktrace from logcat. Kindly try once after cleaning your project

Comment: which is the line LineGraph.java:64?

Comment: layout.addView(mChart);

Answer (score 0):

Guys it was my fault : i added the chart Layout into an other XML, different from the Layout set when onCreate() is called.
Sorry for all that mess and thank you guys for your kindness